# Rails TDD - what to write first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I'm just getting into TDD with Rails.  Something that is puzzling me is "when to write the tests". All guides suggest that you should write the tests before writing any code, but if I create a Person model and then write the following test before writing any code;

```
p = Person.new
p.firstname = "mikey"
p.lastname = "hogarth"
assert_equal p.fullname, "mikey hogarth"
```

then the test itself will not fail, it will crash! Because I haven't implemented the "fullname" method yet, I'll get a runtime error. I therefore can't possibly make that test fail until I've written the code.

How do TDD coders usually approach this sort of situation? Is it basically with dummy method stubs or is there a better way?

===EDIT===

Lots of great ideas suggested. I eventually decided that the following option achieves what I was trying to do most elegantly;

```
if p.respond_to? "fullname"
  assert_equal "Mikey Hogarth", p.fullname
else
  flunk "fullname not implemented"
end
```

===SECOND EDIT===

If you stumble across this answer, it seems my whole approach to TDD was the problem, so while the code above will work it isn't good practice.

Comment: why not try testing if p.fullname is defined?

Comment: I thought it might be something like this, I was playing around with this sort of syntax:

p=Person.new;methods = %q{ name firstname fullname }; methods.each { |method| assert p.respond_to? method }. 

Is this generally how people do it?

Comment: @MikeyHogarth I would recommend you get hold of Kent Beck's Test Driven Development by Example. While it uses Java, the concepts in the book apply to any language. It is considered the "Hello World" book of TDD. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Test-Driven-Development-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321146530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write the code you wish you had. In C style languages/statically compiled languages, the above would not even compile, as you correctly stated the code does not exist. This is fine, you would then implement the bare minimum to make the code build in order to run your tests. In other words, your tests drive your design.

My Ruby is very rusty but in the above example something along the lines of `method_missing` will be thrown for the methods/properties that do not exist. Therefore you would create them.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname

  def fullname

  end
end
```

If you run your test now you will get nil returned from fullname. Therefore we would implement the fullname method. The point to note here is that message has changed, rather than Ruby moaning about missing methods, the test is moaning that we have not implemented the methods correctly.

```
def fullname
   return @firstname + " " + @lastname
end
```

Now your test will pass.

Basically you want to either change the message that your test displays after running (this will prove you are getting somewhere) or you want to make it pass. After the test is passing, you can refactor. The above method is simple, but you could drop the return statement, use string formatting or whatever. As long as the test passes after, you know you're good to go.

Comment: I suspected it would be in writing dummy methods - gonna give it a little while to see if anyone comes up with anything else though.

Comment: As I said, my Ruby/Rails is weak but Corey Haines has a great talk about how to abstract the Rails mess from your Ruby code. Worth checking out, as if the above model relies on ActiveRecord you may have to change your approach slightly. See http://confreaks.net/videos/641-gogaruco2011-fast-rails-tests

Comment: @buruzaemon - good spot. That's why pair programming is effective ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is ok for test code to crash in these situations. Consider it as a fail.

Writing test code before actual code will give you posibility to design interface of the class under test before you actually start implementing this class. You will have an example of the class usage, which is great!

After this you will need to create actual class under test and test will fail, not crash. Then make this test pass, refactor and continue writing failing tests.

Comment: +1 A crashing test *is* a failing test.  You're doing just fine.  TDD requires that you write the tests first.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be to either use 
a conditional check `p.fullname.nil?` for that test, or simply put `assert_not_nil(p.fullname)` as a preceding test, that when failed will prevent the remaining tests from executing.

Comment: This still results in a NoMethod runtime crash, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Your suggestion got me in the right direction - I have edited the OP to show what I ended up doing

Comment: @MikeyHogarth while this helped you out. This is not TDD, and in fact this is a rather horrible way to go about it. You should not need to write custom logic to decide what you need to assert.

Comment: Alright Finglas, I'm defecting to your answer after doing a bit more reading!